# React App without state and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I would like to know if it's fully consistent with the React principles.I made a React App without state and props.I've put pure javascript only inside componentDidMount e.g.

```
componentDidMount(){
  const first = document.getElementById('first');
  const second = document.getElementById('second');
  function funk(){
     console.log(first.innerHTML);
     second.innerHTML = "Arrr";
  }
  funk();
}
```

Of course it's just an example, my app is far more complex.

Comment: you are bypassing most of the goodness that react has to offer with the [diffing algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)

Comment: Why would you do this using React? It doesn't follow React's principles. In very rare cases  I see direct DOM manipulation as necessary

Comment: Thanks! I refactored my code and now everything follow React's principles. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically speaking, You can (as you may already know).
Should you do it? A big and glowing **NO!**.

With this approach of targeting the `DOM` directly, you are bypassing and missing most of the goodness that react has to offer with the [Reconciliation and The Diffing Algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

If you really (really) need to target the `DOM`, you can use react's [ref API](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).
And you can see in their [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs) it's should be used sparingly :

> Don’t Overuse Refs
>   Your first inclination may be to use refs to “make
>   things happen” in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and
>   think more critically about where state should be owned in the
>   component hierarchy. Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to
>   “own” that state is at a higher level in the hierarchy. See the
>   Lifting State Up guide for examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes and no**

**Yes**, you can use it in some cases for utilizing complex jQuery plugins integrating react as a part of your project and so on...

I know that there are lots of haters of such approach but we should also understand business if it's possible to achieve a goal without spending 40-80hrs for coding it yourself - go for it.

**No**, you should not do any DOM manipulation in component live cycle methods unless you are very good with react and completely understand how things work internally in this library.
Changing DOM in such way will most likely cause performance issues because your components will not be able to utilize shadow DOM, as a result, your components will perform DOM manipulation after every change and could potentially slow down the application.